# Wordpress error on godaddy Hosting Klasik Deluxe Windows

Tags: wordpress

I have problem with my wordpress in godaddy, I don't change anything, but when I open web has been like this :

> Warning: require(D:\Hosting\7254975\html/wp-blog-header.php)
>   [function.require]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   D:\Hosting\7254975\html\index.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   'D:\Hosting\7254975\html/wp-blog-header.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in D:\Hosting\7254975\html\index.php
>   on line 17

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)